# Unnecessary allocations using Julia update operators

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection, profiling, julia

Consider the following function:

```
function mytest(x, b)
    y = zeros(x[:,:,1])
    for i in 1:length(b)
        y += b[i] * x[:,:,i]
    end
    return y
end
```

When I run it, I get the following:

```
x = rand(30,30,100000)
b = rand(100000)
@time mytest(x,b)

elapsed time: 0.571765222 seconds (727837732 bytes allocated, 66.49% gc time)
```

Why is it allocating so much memory and spending so much time doing garbage collection?  The code should be type stable, and I would expect the `+=` operator to perform no re-allocation.  However, it seems that it is re-allocating each time it adds two matrices.

Should I consider this to be a bug in Julia?  And more important, how can I write this code in a way that does not re-allocate?

**EDIT:** fixed typo.

Comment: The right hand side `b[i] * x[:,:,i]` first allocates a temporary array with the result of the product before that is added in-place to the left hand side. The temporary array then needs to be garbage collected. At least... that is how it would work with [tag:numpy].

Comment: @moarningsun, thanks for the tip.  My previous experience with performance critical code is mostly using C++ and Eigen, which would not allocate a temporary when taking a slice.  I've changed my code to have three nested for loops, and the allocation problem has been fixed.  (Before that I tried using the ArrayViews package, but that did not seem to fix things.)  I'm still curious if there's a better way.

Comment: @JimGarrison: check out the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/i5hfGpWRHlk). `+=` is just syntactic sugar (for now at least) and so I think it always just re-allocates (but somebody please correct me if I'm wrong). Also, I'd be interested in seeing how the three loop solved your problem.

Comment: Looks like this may be fixed in Julia 0.4: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/9150

Answer (score 4):

@cd98 requested my three-nested-loop solution, which solves the allocation problem but I assume would underperform an equivalent vectorized version.  Here it is:

```
function mytest(x, b)
    d1, d2, d3 = size(x)
    y = zeros(eltype(x), d1, d2)
    for i in 1:d3
        for j in 1:d2
            for k in 1:d1
                y[k,j] += b[i] * x[k,j,i]
            end
        end
    end
    return y
end

x = rand(30,30,100000)
b = rand(100000)
@time mytest(x,b)
@time mytest(x,b)
```

And the output:

```
elapsed time: 0.218220119 seconds (767172 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.197181799 seconds (7400 bytes allocated)
```

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't solve the (original) allocation problem, but I get about a 1.8x speedup by simply wrapping the loops in the latter solution with @inbounds:

```
function mytest_inbounds(x, b)
    d1, d2, d3 = size(x)
    y = zeros(eltype(x), d1, d2)
    @inbounds begin
        for i in 1:d3
            for j in 1:d2
                for k in 1:d1
                    y[k,j] += b[i] * x[k,j,i]
                end
            end
        end
    end
    return y
end

x = rand(30, 30, 100000)
b = rand(100000)
@time mytest(x, b)
@time mytest(x, b)
@time mytest_inbounds(x, b)
@time mytest_inbounds(x, b)
```

Output:

```
elapsed time: 0.39144919 seconds (767212 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.353495867 seconds (7400 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.202614643 seconds (396972 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.193425902 seconds (7400 bytes allocated)
```

Also, lots of good discussion on related issues here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/julia-users/aYS_AvKqPCI/DyTiq4lKIAoJ

Answer (score 3):

There is also the possibility of using [Base.Cartesian](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/devdocs/cartesian/): after `using Base.Cartesian`, you can write

```
@nloops 3 i x begin
  (@nref 2 y i) += b[i_3] * (@nref 3 x i)
end
```

which expands to basically the same loops like in Jim's answer.

Comment: But personally, I think this is ugly and I prefer Jim's solution.